# Python OOP: Difference between attributes in the __init__() bracket and those outside

Tags: python, oop, class, attributes

I have been reading a lot about Python OOP here and in the Python tutorial. But some questions bug me on class attributes.

Example:

```
class Par(object):
    def __init__(self, chip, fig):
        self.fruit = chip
        self.fig = fig
        self.pear =10
```

1. Shouldn't `self.fruit = chip` be `self.chip = chip`?
2. How come `fruit` does not appear in the attribute list in the `__init__()` brackets but it is used?
3. What is the difference between `self.fruit = chip` and `self.chip = chip`?
4. What is the difference between declaring an attribute in the `__init__()` and declaring it outside `__init__()` e.g. `self.pear =10`

Comment: you should not ask multiple questions in a single SO question

Comment: The variables within the parentheses are parameters to the function and not attributes at all.  The questions asked demonstrate a lack of understanding that transcends OOP aspects.  There should be more study done and more specific questions asked to shed light on particular issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` will be an instance of `Par`. `self.__dict__` is a dict which holds attributes of `self`. When you say

```
self.fruit = chip
```

an entry in the dict is created: `self.__dict__` will include `{'fruit':chip}`.

When you say

```
def __init__(self, chip, fig):
```

you are declaring that `Par` must be passed two values, `chip` and `fig`. (The `self` instance will be passed to `__init__` for you.)

So inside the `__init__`, the **local variables** (not attributes!) `chip` and `fig` are known.

`self.fruit = chip` is creating an **attribute** `fruit` with value `chip`.

---

For example,

```
class Par(object):
    def __init__(self, chip, fig):
        self.fruit = chip
        self.fig = fig
        self.pear = 10

# 99 is being passed in as the value of `chip`
# 'bar' is being passed in as the value of `fig`    
par = Par(99,'bar') 
print(par.__dict__)
```

yields

```
{'fruit': 99, 'pear': 10, 'fig': 'bar'}
```

---

Note that to access the attributes you would normally use, for example, `par.fruit` rather than `par.__dict__['fruit']`. I show `par.__dict__` above only to give you a picture of what is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: When one comes from a statically typed language to a dynamic one...there are many wonders. Thanks for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between "self.fruit = chip" and "self.chip =
>   chip"?

There is only one difference. In first case you are storing your `chip` in attribute named `fruit`, whereas in 2nd case, its `chip`. An entry in the `__dict__` attribute of the class, is made for the `LHS` and the `RHS` as the `name-value` pair. LHS denotes the name of the `attribute` you are using to link to the value in the `__dict__` attribute of class. You can have `any name` there..

> How come fruit does not appear in the attribute list in the **init**()
>   brackets but it is used

For the same reason as I wrote above. `fruit` is a class attribute. You declare it in your `__init__` method, and assign the passed value to that `attribute`.

> What is the difference between declaring an attribute in the init()
>   and declaring it outside _init() e.g. "self.pear =10"

Variables declared inside `__init__` are class attributes. They are common for all the instances created for that class. Whereas, attributes that you declare outside, is `instance` specific. So, specifically, every instance of a class can have `different set of attributes.

```
class Demo:
    def __init__(self, name):
        # This attribute is linked to every instance through self parameter, 
        # which contains the reference to the current instance.
        self.name = name   

demo1 = Demo("demo1")

demo2 = Demo("demo2")

demo1.attr = "new Attr"   # Creating Attribute on the fly.

demo2.diffAttr = "diff Attr"
```

**So, in the above code: -**

- The instance `demo1` has two attributes, `name` and `attr`
- And the instance `demo2` also has two attributes, `name` and `diffAttr`, the 2nd attribute is different for both instance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Either one is correct.
2. In python you do not have to declare variables. `self.fruit = chip` creates the variable `self.fruit` and then it assignes to it the value of the `chip` variable
3. `self.fruit = chip` stores the value of `chip` is the `self.fruit` variable, while `self.chip = chip` stores the value of `chip` in `self.chip`
4. `chip` and `flag` do not belong to the Par object. They are just used in order to access the values that are passed to the function when it is called.

The `self` keyword tells the interpreter that the variable following it is member of an object.
In you example, the values for `chip` and `fig` will be lost after the function `__init__` is executed, but the values of `self.fruit`, `self.fig` and `self.pear` will remain for as long as the object leaves. This means they have a diffrent scope.

after the `__init__` function is executed, you can read and modify the values of `self.fruit`, `self.fig` and `self.pear` like this:

```
par = Par(oneChip, oneFig)
print par.fruit
print par.fig
par.pear = 20
print par.pear
```